# Installing packages in Ubuntu 14.04.2.LTS

Tags: configure

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.2.LTS. When I came to load and compile OpenFOAM-2.4.0 it says cmake, flex, bison, qt4 and OpenMPI are not installed.Today I downloaded those files and are in my home directory.So question is how do I compile those or get them into Ubuntu? Please can someone help with the information I have given.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably easier do download and install these packages from the official Ubuntu repositories. Try executing this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev cmake flex bison libqt4-dev
```

EDIT:

You can also install OpenFOAM directly via their package repository, which already contains version 2.4.0, and will install the required dependencies automatically. From the OpenFOAM [website](http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu.php):

```
VERS=$(lsb_release -cs) 
sudo sh -c "echo deb http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu $VERS main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openfoam.list"

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openfoam240
```

Comment: You are welcome! Please consider accepting the answer if you feel your problem has been solved.

Comment: Thanks but problem is I do not have internet connected to PC.Work frm my BlackBerry cell phone.So I need links copy to my cel then transfer to cel.Also need C++ cxx for SU2_EDU program.Can u please help here too.Thanks